# authentication warning when running Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I am getting the following warning when I execute my scripts.

```
[warn] c.d.d.c.Connection - /127.0.0.1:9042 did not send an authentication challenge; This is suspicious because the driver expects authentication (configured auth provider = com.datastax.driver.core.PlainTextAuthProvider)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the reason could be that I have not configured Cassandra to authenticate incoming connection requests. (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureConfigNativeAuth.html)

As I am doing unit-tests, this is not required for the moment. I am happy to accept other answer if my reasoning isn't correct.

Comment: Correct - this happens when the driver has an authenticator set, but the server is not authenticating.

Comment: What do you mean driver has authentication set?